# Magento dropdown attribute labels

Tags: database, magento, attributes, label

Can anyone tell me where dropdown attribute text values are stored in DB?
I see int values in catalog_product_entity_int, but I can't find their text labels...

Comment: Found them in eav_attribute_option_value!

Answer (score 3):

Try table `eav_attribute_option_value`.

Comment: You should explain your solution a bit more.

Comment: I'm not sure what more I can add? The question is where attribute text values are stored in the Magento database - the answer is that they are stored in that table. I don't think a long-winded discussion of EAV attributes is really appropriate here (and if it is, then I'm not the person to write it I'm afraid!)

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer says the correct table is `eav_attribute_option_value`

Here is some more explanation though (it seems that what's necessary here is the steps to get the labels for a particular attribute code - looking in this table won't make it readily apparent).

To retrieve labels/options do the following:

- find the `attribute_id` for your `attribute_code` from the `eav_attribute` table
- get all the `option_id`'s for your `attribute_id` from the `eav_attribute_option` table
- get all the `value`'s (labels) for the `option_id`'s that you have for your `store_id` from the `eav_attribute_option_value` table

In other words you need to get your attributes' `id` and from there get all the options associated with it.

Since each option can have different text depending on your store/language settings you need then to go to the last table and get all of the `value`'s

Hope this was helpful

Comment: Given this info, does anyone have an explanation for how the relationships are stored? I would expect this relationship to look something like: catalog_product_entity should be a foreign key in  catalog_product_index_eav, which has reference to the eav_attribute (and the catalog_product_entity)